# sharedPreferences commit, return true but actually failed

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Here is part of the code:

```
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("example", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String examplee = sharedPreferences.getString("examplee", "");
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("examplee",examplee + "|" + string + "|").commit();
```

On most devices, 'commit' returns true and the data is really updated in the data folder,but on several devices,though returns true,the data is not updated,I am really confused about this and tried many times to fix it.

Can someone help me about this?I'm truly grateful for your help.

Comment: can you use `apply()` and see the results?

Comment: `apply()` doesn't have the Boolean return value.

Comment: Can you specify the devices does this code worked and does not worked?

Answer (score 0):

OK,finally I found that this problem is caused by using SharedPreferences in multiprocess.

Now,I use [Tray](https://github.com/grandcentrix/tray) to replace the SharedPreferences.